# Insert data into mysql table using jpa annotations

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I have two tables currently in my database.

table1:

```
id | name | firstname | lastname
```

table2:

```
id | phone | empId
```

I have used JPA annotations to make an object on table table2.

This goes something like this:

```
{@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "phone")
private Long phone;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="empid", referencedColumnName = "id" ,insertable=false, updatable=false)
private table1 tab1;
}
```

Now I have used GET method to get the results of the employee along with phonenumber based on

- table2's id.
- phone.
- table2's id and phone.
- name.

Which are working fine.

Now I want to insert a row just in 2nd table(table2).

Just want to push only phone no so that it would just be another insertion only in table2.How can I achieve that as my object contains tab1 as well?

Comment: You mean that the tab1 that your table2 object references is already stored in the database ?

Comment: Have you tried em.persist(phone)?

Comment: an annotation won't "persist" anything. It stores information and nothing else.

Comment: @JihedAmine Yeah! Consider emp having multiple phone numbers

Comment: I think it will work fine, meaning that the persistence layer will detect that the tab1 table exists (based on its id) and will not create a duplicate but link to the existing record when you persist table2.